# constructor of base class works but its effect gets cancelled

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, c++17

I have the following code:

item.h

```cpp
using item_t = char;
    
constexpr item_t no_item = '*';
constexpr item_t item1 = 'a';
constexpr item_t item2 = 'b';
    
bool isItem(const item_t &item) {
    return item == no_item || item == item1 || item == item2;
}
        
class base {
public:
    base() : value(no_item) {}
    base(const item_t &item) : value(item) {}
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const base &b) {
        out << b.value;
    }
    /*other stuff*/
private:
    item_t value;
};
                
template<bool(*check)(const item_t&)> 
class derivedTmp : base {
public:
    derivedTmp() : base() {}
    derivedTmp(item_t item) {
        if (!check(item)) {
            base::base();
        }
        else {
            base::base(item);
        }
    }
};

using derived = derivedTmp<isItem>;
const derived d1(item1);
const derived d2(item2);
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "item.h"
    
int main() {
    cout << item1 << "\t" << item2 << "\n";
}
```

I really do not understand why it does not work. If there is some syntax error, it doesn't care because it means I made a mistake but the program compiles good; the output is `*     *` instead of `a     b` as I expect. Can anyone explain to me why? I’m using C++17 in Visual Studio 19.

Comment: `if(!check(item)) { base::base(); }` - um.... what is that supposed to be? `base` portion of derivation is already constructed. You can't "reconstruct" it.

Comment: calling the default constructor of base otherwise the other constructor, how is possible that base portion is already constructed, I did not call the constructor

Comment: As I said, the base class constructor is already fired (one way or another) by the time you enter the `{` of the derived ctor. You can't just redo that. I'm struggling to see how a single constructor with a single reference argument with a default reference to `no_item` can't solve whatever you're *really* trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Linus “*how is possible that base portion is already constructed, I did not call the constructor*” - if you don’t explicitly call a base class constructor from the member initialization list of the derived class constructor, the compiler will implicitly call the base class’s default constructor for you. Base classes are *always* fully constructed before the *body* of a derived constructor begins running.

Answer (score 1):

```
const derived d1(item1);
```

The above invokes `derivedTmp(item_t item)` constructor.

This will first invoke the default base constructor which is `base::base()` which sets `value` to `no_item` i.e. '*'.

Comment: I m sorry but you are wrong, `deriveTmp(item_t item)` invoke `base::base(val)` because `!check(val)` is false

Comment: Have a look at https://godbolt.org/z/dhKrje to understand the point. If you don't call a proper base class constructor in the derived one, the default one is called while creating the base component of the derived object.

Comment: By the time it starts executing what is inside the braces `{...}` in the constructor, the default base constructor is already fired and completed.

Comment: does it mean I should use an assignment operator?

Comment: That's one solution. Or a public/protected setter function in the base class that can be used to reset 'value' member.

Answer (score 1):

The only place you can call a base class constructor, let alone pass parameters to it, is from in the [*member initialization list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) of the derived constructor, eg:

```cpp
template<bool(*check)(const item_t&)> 
class derivedTmp : public base {
public:
    derivedTmp() = default;
    derivedTmp(item_t item) : base(check(item) ? item : no_item) {}
};
```

The reason your code doesn’t work is because both of your derived constructors are initializing the base class using its parameter-less default constructor, which sets the `value` member to `no_item`. Calling the `base` constructor inside the *body* of the `derived` constructor does not *reset* the base class to update the `value` like you are thinking.  If it even compiles at all ( it does not in several compilers I tried), it would instead construct temporary `base` objects that simply go out of scope and get destroyed immediately, leaving the calling `derived` object unchanged.